# NodeJS parquet-reader - how to read from a variable instead of file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, parquet

I started using `node-parquet` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-parquet) (src: https://github.com/mvertes/node-parquet) and it is explained how we can read parquet data from a file:

```
var reader = new np.ParquetReader('myfile.parquet');
```

How to read parquet from a text variable instead of a file (text variable contains actual parquet data).

Right now I am forced to save that text/parquet variable to into a file and then read it with above code..